# Jquery Problem With Changing Element Attribute In Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I am using Jquery to create dynamic links based on user input. I have a set of elements in my
ajax loaded div that looks like this

```
<div class="mxcell">
<input type="text" size="40" class="input_name" value="">
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="dyn_link">
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/images/arrow_right.gif">
</a>
</div>
```

Now in Jquery I write

```
$(function(){
$("#right").delegate(".input_name", "change", function(){
var dyn_link = $(this).val()
$(this).parent().find("a").attr("href", "http://www.example.com/"+ dyn_link +".html");
});
});
```

This works fine in Chrome/Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer.

Any ideas?

IE debugger pointed to Jquery line 69 character 15. Wouldn't know to investigate it further.

**UPDATE:**

I solved the above by using focusOut() instead of change()

But am not still sure whether there is a better solution

Comment: Well, on changing the value in inputfeld,  a dynamic link is created such as href = 'http://www.example.com/apples.html'. In IE this remains href="#"

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/pNZTe/

I'd `keyup` instead of `focusOut`, and I cleaned up your href changer a bit:

```
$("#right").delegate(".input_name", "keyup", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var dyn_link = $this.val();
    $this.next("a").attr("href","http://www.example.com/" + dyn_link + ".html");
});
```